# Custom Field in Page Title

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, shortcode

I need to show a custom Field in a title (CPT) I have this code

```
function wpse_224340_document_title($title){
    global $post; // make sure the post object is available to us
    if(is_singular('mec-events')){ // check we're on a single post
        $release_author = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'mec_fields_2', true);
        if($release_author != ""){ $title["title"].= " (" . $release_author. ")"; }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

But it doesn´t work, someone can help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `wp_title` filter, which passes the current title, separator, and location as arguments. It then appends the custom field value to the title if the conditions are meet. For more details :- Visit Link [**wp_title**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/)

```
function wpse_224340_document_title($title, $sep, $seplocation) {
    global $post;

    // make sure the post object is available to us
    if (is_singular('mec-events')) { // check we're on a single post
        $release_author = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mec_fields_2', true);

        if ($release_author !== "") {
            $title .= " (" . $release_author . ")";
        }
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter('wp_title', 'wpse_224340_document_title', 10, 3);
```